# Gmail strip equal sign (=) in html email

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpmailer

I try to send html email using php mailer, and all of my equal signs on this email is stripped

what i try to send:

```
<a href="https://youtube.com">Check this link</a>

==========================================================

<p style="color: green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non mattis nisl. Sed viverra purus at nisi blandit, eu malesuada ligula feugiat. Vivamus blandit semper dapibus. Nulla hendrerit maximus enim, sit amet pellentesque urna ullamcorper quis. Duis non gravida odio. Curabitur vel molestie libero. Aenean venenatis lorem ac odio pretium, quis vehicula diam efficitur. Maecenas massa ante, dignissim facilisis quam vel, fringilla ultricies nibh. Vestibulum laoreet ligula eget lacus viverra volutpat. Sed a molestie nunc, ut venenatis odio. Phasellus egestas gravida libero in commodo. Etiam ultrices egestas sapien dictum venenatis. Donec eu malesuada justo, quis pellentesque arcu. Praesent ultrices luctus maximus. Praesent commodo tincidunt tellus, non vestibulum orci laoreet vel. Quisque egestas rhoncus pulvinar.</p>

<p style="color: red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non mattis nisl. Sed viverra purus at nisi blandit, eu malesuada ligula feugiat. Vivamus blandit semper dapibus. Nulla hendrerit maximus enim, sit amet pellentesque urna ullamcorper quis. Duis non gravida odio. Curabitur vel molestie libero. Aenean venenatis lorem ac odio pretium, quis vehicula diam efficitur. Maecenas massa ante, dignissim facilisis quam vel, fringilla ultricies nibh. Vestibulum laoreet ligula eget lacus viverra volutpat. Sed a molestie nunc, ut venenatis odio. Phasellus egestas gravida libero in commodo. Etiam ultrices egestas sapien dictum venenatis. Donec eu malesuada justo, quis pellentesque arcu. Praesent ultrices luctus maximus. Praesent commodo tincidunt tellus, non vestibulum orci laoreet vel. Quisque egestas rhoncus pulvinar.</p>
```

what i get in email:

```
<a href"https://youtube.com">Check this link</a>

<p style"color: green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non mattis nisl. Sed viverra purus at nisi blandit, eu malesuada ligula feugiat. Vivamus blandit semper dapibus. Nulla hendrerit maximus enim, sit amet pellentesque urna ullamcorper quis. Duis non gravida odio. Curabitur vel molestie libero. Aenean venenatis lorem ac odio pretium, quis vehicula diam efficitur. Maecenas massa ante, dignissim facilisis quam vel, fringilla ultricies nibh. Vestibulum laoreet ligula eget lacus viverra volutpat. Sed a molestie nunc, ut venenatis odio. Phasellus egestas gravida libero in commodo. Etiam ultrices egestas sapien dictum venenatis. Donec eu malesuada justo, quis pellentesque arcu. Praesent ultrices luctus maximus. Praesent commodo tincidunt tellus, non vestibulum orci laoreet vel. Quisque egestas rhoncus pulvinar.</p>

<p style"color: red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non mattis nisl. Sed viverra purus at nisi blandit, eu malesuada ligula feugiat. Vivamus blandit semper dapibus. Nulla hendrerit maximus enim, sit amet pellentesque urna ullamcorper quis. Duis non gravida odio. Curabitur vel molestie libero. Aenean venenatis lorem ac odio pretium, quis vehicula diam efficitur. Maecenas massa ante, dignissim facilisis quam vel, fringilla ultricies nibh. Vestibulum laoreet ligula eget lacus viverra volutpat. Sed a molestie nunc, ut venenatis odio. Phasellus egestas gravida libero in commodo. Etiam ultrices egestas sapien dictum venenatis. Donec eu malesuada justo, quis pellentesque arcu. Praesent ultrices luctus maximus. Praesent commodo tincidunt tellus, non vestibulum orci laoreet vel. Quisque egestas rhoncus pulvinar.</p>
```

it makes my link and inline styling not working.

i use laravel mail, this is my 'routes.php' file

```
Route::get('/send-mail', function(){
    Mail::to("from@mail.com")->send(new Test());
});

this is my mail file code

    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Test extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build(){
        return $this->from('sender@mail.com')
                ->view('te.test');
    }
}
```

Raw Source
[image]

Comment: You'll need to show what PHP code you've got to execute this.

Comment: @Qirel, i use laravel mail function `php artisan make:mail Mail`. I'll update my question

Comment: You can try html entity value `&equals;` to send or can add the following line in your html template:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @PintuKumar i have added that meta in my html template, and `&equals;` not working

Comment: HTML entities will survive, but they will prevent attributes from working, so that’s not a solution. I’d suspect a mismatched content-transfer-encoding header. Can you show raw message source as received, including headers?

Comment: @Synchro updated my question, sorry i can't add it as code because it's too long

Comment: This just looks like a bug in Laravel's email function. I suggest reporting it as such.

Comment: @Synchro i've done with it, i solved it by replacing all (=) to (=3D)

Comment: In that case it sounds like while your header declared that your message body is in quoted-printable format, you hadn't actually applied quoted-printable encoding to the body.